# VSTS How to deploy the compiled "published" app to IIS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Setting up the VSTS CI process. I have a build setup and a release. It "works" in the sense that it puts files on the IIS server correctly. What it doesn't do is copy the published files to IIS. It's just copying the build files.

And to make sure I'm not using the wrong terminology here. In visual studio, when you build, it builds each project individually. When you "publish" (whether to a local directory or to an IIS server), it compiles all those files into a proper IIS ready set of files.

In other words, I expect a single webconfig and bin directory. What I get is a directory for each project in the solution with its own bin.

I'm using the .net Desktop template for the build and IIS website deployment template for the release definition.

I feel like I'm missing a step in there but I was following the tutorial on how to do this. But no bueno :(

Comment: What's the detail MSbuild argument are you using in the build step? Do you have multiple web projects? And are they in a single solution or multiple solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to work on this lately. I think I quickly tried your solution below and got a build error. So I just left it alone for now. This is far too complex for such a simple workflow. But that's MS for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple tutorials about how to perform IIS web Deploy through TFS/VSTS in google.

The fist thing should make sure you have used the properly MSBuild Argument in your build task. For example, if you want to package the build result to a single file:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

You can set up Copy and Publish Build Artifacts to copy zip package to share. In this task you could determine which files/folder will be published.

Once your package is ready, we’re behind two steps to deployed app:

- create and run site and app pool – WinRM – IIS Web App Management
- publish our app – WinRM – IIS Web App Deployment

For details step you could refer this tutorial-- [IIS web deploy by vsts](https://iamkarlson.space/2017/02/27/iis-web-deploy-by-vsts/)

Besides  you could also create a publish profile file(xxxx.pubxml) for the  multiple web app projects. Using the publish file to publish your web apps. Make sure the publish file name is same. In your build definition, specify the publish file: `“/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=xxxx”`.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use web deploy publish method if the IIS server can be accessed from build agent.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Staging /p:Password=hdNSWsbuqno7J5uqnwKafwlfNPt1DSco7J5uqnwKafwlfNPt1DSpKHuYgCco7J5 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true
```

Some articles can help you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1184858/Deploying-a-Web-App-from-a-Command-Line-using-MSBu